# Change location of header.php and footer.php

Tags: templates, directory, footer, custom-header

I wish to organize the my themes directory a little more.
Is it possible to move `header.php` and `footer.php` to a sub directory?

I guess it's done by hooking on to some action, but is it possible with just a config setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to override header/footer via hooks in respective `get_header()`/`get_header()` functions.

However it is often overlooked that these function allow input and loading *different* headers.

For example `get_header( 'nested/header' );` will look for `header-nested/header.php` in theme's folder. It's kind of a hack in regards to subdirectory use, but it works. :)

Comment: Well, it works, but I would need both a `nested-header` directory and a `nested-footer` directory. I guess I'll just leave the at the root then. A way to do it might be write a function of my own, that loads the files, and triggers the correct actions, but then I would need to maintain it manually for every update. Thanks for the answer! :)